# Get unique counts from one data frame as values in another data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes and I want to get some unique row counts from one dataframe (`responses`) as column values in the other dataframe (`contacts`)

```
import pandas as pd

contacts = pd.read_csv('contacts.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
responses = pd.read_csv('campaign_responses.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

contacts.head()

    contact_id          job_title  country  Email    Webinar
0   0031B00002cPLuFQAW  manager    US       0        0
1   0031B00002Z2zMYQAZ  admin      UK       0        0
2   003a000001nHioCAAS  manager    DE       0        0
```

Note: Email and Webinar will be 0 for all rows. They're placeholder values for the moment.

```
responses.head()

    campaign_type      contact_id
0   Email              0031B00002cPLuFQAW
1   Webinar            0031B00002Z2zMYQAZ
2   Webinar            0031B00002cPLuFQAW
3   Webinar            0031B00002cPLuFQAW
4   Email              003a000001nHioCAAS
5   Email              003a000001nHioCAAS
```

I'd like to get a count of how many times each contact has responded to each campaign type as an attribute in the contacts data frame.

The final `contacts` data frame should look like this (based on the data above)

```
    contact_id          job_title  country  Email    Webinar
0   0031B00002cPLuFQAW  manager    US       1        2
1   0031B00002Z2zMYQAZ  admin      UK       0        1
2   003a000001nHioCAAS  manager    DE       2        0
```

Comment: The first block of code you've posted is irrelevant to the question and could be edited out.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need

```
pd.crosstab(df.contact_id,df.campaign_type)
Out[37]: 
campaign_type       Email  Webinar
contact_id                        
0031B00002Z2zMYQAZ      0        1
0031B00002cPLuFQAW      1        2
003a000001nHioCAAS      2        0
```

Comment: @user3483203 no worry man , always someone doing this ..:-) BTW , thank you

Comment: Cool! This is great for summarizing the responses dataframe, for sure. I omitted some of the columns in the `contacts` data frame (to keep this example simple; I've updated it) so I do want to join the contacts dataframe with the responses dataframe. Any advice on how I can do that?

Comment: @JoeFusaro you can update . `contact=contact.set_index('contact_id'); contact.update(pd.crosstab(df.contact_id,df.campaign_type))`

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something... I did as you suggested, but the `contacts` dataframe does not update with the added columns. It works if I just do the crosstab operation on the responses dataframe, but the rows are not added to `contacts` -- my full script + output here: https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/909f4ce857a66dd978c70c08a26e9462

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple:

```
df.groupby(['contact_id', 'campaign_type']).size().unstack('type', fill_value=0)
```

---

**Edit:** neither short nor simple, see other answer.